# Add MVC Controller with Views Using Entity Framework (2.0)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Controller will not create when adding a new MVC 5 controller with Views using Entity Framework.

The error message is:

[image: Error Message]

The Output window:

```
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
Attempting to compile the application in memory.
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'DayRateEmps'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
User profile is available.
Using 'C:\Users\xxx.yyy\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project and it might solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your application and try again. If that doesn't work then your entity model is not working right. In my case my entity model was in another project folder hence i was unable to auto generate any of the controller. So i manually made a controller an empty controller and imported that project and model.